# Magento2: extension import products .xml file

Tags: magento2, extensions

I am looking for extension which I can import products to website via .xml file feed and live update by cron.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one it's also free version also

https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html

You can also connect Google drive files